# Renaming a section of filename for multiple files in powershell or command prompt

Tags: command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, rename, batch-rename

I have some 100s of files having names like this:

```
MOD15A2H.A2012001.h26v06.001.2015230181014_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012009.h26v06.001.2015236194306_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012017.h26v06.001.2015237120626_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012025.h26v06.001.2015237124147_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012033.h26v06.001.2015237131607_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012041.h26v06.001.2015237232610_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012049.h26v06.001.2015238141341_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012057.h26v06.001.2015238172148_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012065.h26v06.001.2015238191713_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012073.h26v06.001.2015238174737_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012081.h26v06.001.2015239174812_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012089.h26v06.001.2015240024933_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012097.h26v06.001.2015240043222_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012105.h26v06.001.2015240142201_LAI500m.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012113.h26v06.001.2015240161909_LAI500m.tif
```

I need to rename them as

```
L2012001.tif
L2012009.tif etc.,
```

I am attempting to rename them in bulk through Powershell commands
As far till now, I replaced `"MOD15A2H.A"` with `"L"` and `".h26v06.001."` with `""` using the following in powershell

```
>get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace 'MOD15A2H.A','L'}
>get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace '.h26v06.001.',''}
```

Now please give me any suggestion on removing the remaining part of the name which is different for all the files.

Answer (score 1):

If I have 10 files in a specific directory that are all .txt files, and I want to change the extensions to .xml, I can navigate to the directory, and type:

```
ren *.txt *.xml
```

Comment: You're a new contributer, so I don't want to be mean & downvote you, but you should remove ithis answer. If you re-read the OP, the question concerns creating a new basename from the original basename while retaining the same extension. There is no simple wildcard solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [regular expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7#substitutions-in-regular-expressions), with `.` to [match any character except newline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7#whitespace) in your search-for expression.

Possibly useful:

https://powershellexplained.com/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression/

https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this (You will need to escape dots by backslash in Regex):

```
Get-Childitem -recurse | Foreach {
  Get-Item $File.Fullname | Rename-Item {$_.name -replace 'MOD15A2H\.A','L'}
  Get-Item $File.Fullname | Rename-Item {$_.name -replace '\.h26v06\.001\.',','}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Get-Item` and `Split` with `foreach`:

```bat
get-childitem "F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\*.tif" -recurse |  % { rename-item $_.fullname -newname ('L'+$_.name.split('A.*/')[3]+$_.Extension) -WhatIf }
```

- Or, using aliases...

```bat
gi "F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\*.tif" | % { ren $_.fullname -new ('L'+$_.name.split('.A*/')[-6]+$_.Extension) -WhatIf }
```

- Your outputs using **`-WhatIf`**

```bat
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\MOD15A2H.A2012001.h26v06.001.230181014_LAI500m.tif Destination: F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\L2012001.tif".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\MOD15A2H.A2012009.h26v06.001.236194306_LAI500m.tif Destination: F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\L2012009.tif".
```

---

- The output generated by **`-WhatIf`** allows you to preview the execution, but to effectively rename your files, just remove it:

```bat
get-childitem "F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\*.tif" -recurse |  % { rename-item $_.fullname -newname ('L'+$_.name.split('A.*/')[3]+$_.Extension) -WhatIf}

ls -r "F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\*.tif" | % { ren $_.fullname -new ('L'+$_.name.split('.A*/')[-6]+$_.Extension) -WhatIf}
```

- Output results

```bat
MOD15A2H.A2012001.h26v06.001.230181014_LAI500m.tif  ⇿  L2012001.tif
MOD15A2H.A2012009.h26v06.001.236194306_LAI500m.tif  ⇿  L2012009.tif
```

---

**Obs.:**
An alternative for your case, since the strings in the name are fixed, you can use substring to easily compose the new name:

```bat
      MOD15A2H.A2012001.h26v06.001.2015230181014_LAI500m.tif
'L' +|_________|(10,07)|___________________________________|+ '.tif'          
      MOD15A2H.A2012001.h26v06.001.2015230181014_LAI500m.tif

get-childitem "F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\*.tif" -recurse | % { rename-item $_.fullname -newname ('L'+$_.basename.Substring(10,7)+$_.Extension)}

ls "F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\*.tif" -r|% {ren $_.fullname -new ('L'+$_.basename.Substring(10,7)+'.tif')}
```

---

- And you have the same output / results:

```bat
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\MOD15A2H.A2012001.h26v06.001.230181014_LAI500m.tif Destination: F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\L2012001.tif".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\MOD15A2H.A2012009.h26v06.001.236194306_LAI500m.tif Destination: F:\MOD15A2H_GTiFF\LAI\L2012009.tif".
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√]  **[Split](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)**

  [√]  **[% | Foreach](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html)**

  [√]  **[ls | Get-Item](https://ss64.com/ps/get-item.html)**

  [√]  **[ren | Rename-Item](https://ss64.com/ps/rename-item.html)**

Answer (score 0):

One good [regular expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-5.1) should do it:

```
( Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse ) |
     Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^MOD15A2H\.A(\w+)\..+(\.tif)$', 'L$1$2' }
```

## Breaking it down:

**'^MOD15A2H.A(\w+)..+(.tif)$':**

```
          ^ - Beeginnig of string
MOD15A2H\.A - Literal match for "MOD15A2H.A"
      (\w+) - Capture group 1: one or more word characters
         \. - Match first "." after word characters
         .+ - Match all charaters up to capture group 2
    (\.tif) - Captrue group 2: ".tif"
          $ - End of string
```

**'L$1$2':**

```
 L - Literal "L"
$1 - Capture Group 1
$2 - Capture Group 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the part of the filename that you want to keep is always between the first and second occurance of `.` you can also `.split('.')[1]` and then only replace `A` with `L`

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Install\tesfile -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $NewName = ($_.Name.Split('.')[1] -replace "A","L") + $_.Extension
    Rename-Item $_.FullName $NewName
}
```